# Connect Four Shift left Shift right index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to implement a connect 4 with ai I found in the net and I'm giving it a bit of a twist. I'm trying to add a shift left shift right move. 
Shift left - ABCDEFG -> GABCDEF
Shift Right - ABCDEFG -> BCDEFGA
I've tried adding this to the legal moves

```
public boolean placeMove(int column, int player){         
    //if(!isLegalMove(column)) {System.out.println("Illegal move!"); return false;}
    if (column == 8){
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 7; y--) {
                if(y == 0){
                    board[x][0] = board[x][6];
                }
                else board[x][y] = board[x][y--];
            }
        }
    }
    else if (column == 9){
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
                if(y == 5){
                    board[x][5] = board[x][0];
                }
                else board[x][y] = board[x][y++];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for(int i=5;i>=0;--i){
            if(board[i][column] == 0) {
                board[i][column] = (byte)player;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, it's returning an arrayindexoutofbounds exception. Can someone point out where I went wrong here? Thanks

Here is the board declaration if it would help

```
byte[][] board = new byte[6][7];

public Board1(){
    board = new byte[][]{
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},    
    };
}
```

Comment: On a question and answer site, it is a good idea to read through enough questions to understand what people expect from them. For instance, over and over and over, people here are told to copy and paste the error message into the question. Java errors tell you the module, method, and line number on which the error occurred, there is NO reason to guess all that, or figure it out from (possibly incomplete) source.

Comment: It could be here `board[x][y] = board[x][y++];` but without the stacktrace it is just a guess.

Comment: *"Shift left - ABCDEFG -> GABCDEF"* No, `ABCDEFG` -> `GABCDEF` is a **right** shift with wraparound. To perform such a *right* shift in-place, you take the last value (`G`) and store it temporarily in a hold variable, then copy second-last to last, third-last to second-last, ... first to second, and finally the held value into first position. Nowhere in your code do you store a value in a temporary hold, so even if code hadn't thrown exception, you definitely wouldn't get a shift with wrap-around, since some value would for sure be overridden.

Comment: This ``for (int y = 0; y < 7; y--)`` will quickly put ``y = -1`` which will definitely cause an array index out of bounds when you try to ``board[x][y] = board[x][y--]``. Either than that, there might be other places where the code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 7; y--) {
            if(y == 0){
                board[x][0] = board[x][6];
            }
            else board[x][y] = board[x][y--];
        }
    }
```

in the second for loop, you have y = 0, then you're decrementing y and trying to access it in 'else board[x][y] = board[x][y--]', where once again you are decrementing it. after the first iteration, y will be -1. Which isn't a valid index. I would look through this logic again and if you have to, write out each iteration and write what values are what.

Throughout, you are double incrementing/decrementing y values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I noticed it too and replaced it with 
                for (int y = 5; y >= 0; y--) {
                    if(y == 0){
                        board[x][0] = board[x][6];
                    }
                    else board[x][y] = board[x][y--];
                }
It removed the errors, but it still won't shift the values.

Comment: you're still decrementing y twice, first in your else statement and second after each iteration. is this intentional? you'll be skipping over columns

Comment: Also! y-- decrements AFTER the value is used. so board[x][y] = board[x][y--] is not replacing anything because y will take the value of y-1 after the operation. instead, try board[x][y] = board[x][y-1]

Comment: holy. i forgot that decrement and -1 isnt the same. thank you. I also replaced the shift right with y+1, however it's returning a index out of bounds exception. im gonna simulate it in paper

Comment: in the if(column==9), you are going until y==7. you have a check in there for if(y==5), but if y==6, it will then be trying to set board[x][y]=board[x][y+1], where y+1 is 7 and out of bounds